# Physical Meaning of a Quantum Field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory

Sorry in advance if this question doesn't make sense.

Anyway, I am reading a paper about quantum field theory and the Whitman Axioms (http://users.ox.ac.uk/~mert2060/GeomQuant/Wightman-Axioms.pdf), and it describes a field ($Ψ$) as

$$Ψ:M\rightarrow V\otimes\text{End}(D)$$

where $M$ is a spacetime manifold, $V$ is a vector space, and $D$ is a dense subspace of a Hilbert space.  My question is what $V\otimes\text{End}(D)$ physically represents?

Once again thanks for any help.

Comment: As written, the question is unanswerable. What it "represents" depends on what exactly $D$ and $V$ are and what theory exactly you are talking about (i.e. what Lagrangian). The meaning is very different if it is a gauge field vs. a spinor field vs. a Goldstone boson vs. ...

Comment: *The* Hilbert space?

Comment: Perhaps you could cite the relevant paper for context.

Comment: The paper is about the Whitman Axioms: http://users.ox.ac.uk/~mert2060/GeomQuant/Wightman-Axioms.pdf